# Where to include the Summer School or Winter School participation in the curriculum vitae (CV)?

Tags: cv, summer-school, curriculum

I would like to include a **Winter School** I attended last year in my CV. I am not sure which heading of the CV this should be added to. Should I make a new heading called **Participation** and add this single Winter School there? (Along with 2 other conferences I participated in? or it is not so important to mention the conferences I attended?)

This is how I have included it so far: [My CV](https://ali.mk/cv/amkcv.pdf). Do you think it makes sense? Or better if I format it in another way?

Please let me know of your kind opinion.
Thank you.

Comment: This might vary depending on what jobs you are applying to, but generally in academia, at least early in your career, you would likely want to include conferences attended on your CV. A header such as "Conferences and Workshops" might work well on your CV and you could include the winter school under this heading along with the conferences you have attended.

Answer (score 2):

I have included a sub-section as "Non-Formal Education" under main section "Education" where I put important courses. You can put recent/important summer schools/ online courses/ conference participation under that.

I have seen some people list them in Skills and competencies as a supplement for a specific skill.
Hope that clarifies your problem...